# How can i make pageView.Builder occupy all available space in flutter?

Tags: flutter, widget

I am trying to swap two widgets on button click  OR is there any other way to do this?

When i set
SizedBox(
height: double.infinity,
width: double.infinity, )
it gives error: `BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.`  it works when manually set height and width.
I tried using
Expanded and flexible it gives error like this

```
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#8b1a5 relayoutBoundary=up14 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'
```

Code

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController _uri = TextEditingController();
  bool flag=false;

  bool swap = false;
   int _index = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    swap = widget.swap;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    Widget swapWidget;
    if (!swap) {
      swapWidget =  Center(
        child: Expanded(
        // card height
          child: PageView.builder(
            itemCount: 2,
            controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.95),
            onPageChanged: (int index) => setState(() => _index = index),
            itemBuilder: (_, i) {
              return Transform.scale(
                scale: i == _index ? 1 : 0.9,
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 6,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "Card ${i + 1}",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          
        
        )
        )
      );
    } else {
      swapWidget =new Card(
        child:Text('Nothing To show')
      );
    }

    var swapTile = new ListTile(
      title: swapWidget,
    );


    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar( title: Text('My APP')),
      body: new ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            swapTile,
          ],
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

What i am doing Wrong?
Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do here, but Few things. `PageView` widget expands to the maximum allowed space by default, so you don't need the Expanded or Center widget around it.

Second, I don't know why you would want to wrap `Card` widget with `ListTile`. You certainly can, but that's not how ListTile and Card are designed.

Third, because PageView widget can expand, it needs some size constraints, so it cannot be put inside a infinitely large widget like ListView, so you can remove that, and here is what I have. I hope it is close to what you were looking for.

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool swap = true;
  int _index = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget swapWidget;
    if (swap) {
      swapWidget = PageView.builder(
        itemCount: 2,
        controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.95),
        itemBuilder: (_, i) {
          return Transform.scale(
            scale: i == _index ? 1 : 0.9,
            child: Card(
              elevation: 6,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  "Card ${i + 1}",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    } else {
      swapWidget = Card(child: Text('Nothing To show'));
    }

    return Scaffold(
      body: swapWidget,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah i just figured that out. Thanks for help :)